# Neo4j Cypher Pattern comprehension and SKIP/LIMIT

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I intensively use the Neo4j Cypher Pattern comprehension, for example:

```
[(jobable)-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c1:Criterion)<-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) | {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1} ] AS jobableWeightedCriterion
```

and realized that the returned data from the Pattern comprehension query could be quite big. Is it possible to control the amount of the data returned from the  Pattern comprehension  part of the query.. for example something like SKIP/LIMIT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, pattern comprehension returns a list, so you can apply a skip and limit, to the list like this:

```
[(jobable)-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c1:Criterion)<-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) | 
 {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1} ][$skip..$skip + $limit] AS jobableWeightedCriterion
```

For, skip value 5 and limit 5, it will look like this:

```
[(jobable)-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c1:Criterion)<-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) | 
 {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1} ][5..10] AS jobableWeightedCriterion
```